# background-color on specific div appearing on whole page

Tags: css

I'm working on this page:
http://broadcasted.tv/

My headings have the following (I know it should be a class, I was just doing some testing)

```
 #title-container {
 background-color: #333;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 15px;
 }
```

It works fine everywhere except there
http://broadcasted.tv/user/2/albertmarch/

And I can't figure out why the heading is the whole page... Missing div ??

Any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: First: I see there are 10 instances of `title-container` on that page, so yes, use classes instead of IDs. Secondly, I don't see the "whole page" w/ a background color of #333; just the title bars. What browser are you using? (I'm in Chrome.)

Comment: Much probably an unclosed div tag. And, as mentioned before, IDs should be unique.

Comment: @praguian yeah sorry, I was playing around with it.

Comment: Found that missing div. thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background goes away if you add clear:

```
#title-container {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix... I found a missing closing div and it fixed it!

Comment: @Webberig just a Q: wouldn´t it be impractical to have a clear on a class? (I can understand it if it was an id, but surely you could end up in trouble later when reusing classes?

Comment: It really depends on your page structure. If every .title-container element can cause trouble like that, you can put a clear on the class. Sometimes people use utility classes for things like clear. ie. <div class="title-container clear"> and define .clear { clear: left; } in your CSS